# Swashbuckle adding 200 OK response automatically to generated Swagger file

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I am building swagger docs using Swashbuckle in my WebApi 2 project.

I have the following definition of the method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(Reservation))]
[Route("reservations")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Type = typeof(Reservation))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) ]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict)]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]        
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReserveTickets([FromBody] ReserveTicketsRequest reserveTicketRequest)
{
    // ...
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, response);
}
```

However the generated Swagger file contains HTTP 200 OK as well, although it's not specified anywhere.

```yml
/reservations: 
  post: 
    tags: 
      - "Booking"
    operationId: "Booking_ReserveTickets"
    consumes: 
      - "application/json"
      - "text/json"
    produces: 
      - "application/json"
      - "text/json"
    parameters: 
      - 
        name: "reserveTicketRequest"
        in: "body"
        required: true
        schema: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/ReserveTicketsRequest"
    responses: 
      200: 
        description: "OK"
        schema: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/Reservation"
      201: 
        description: "Created"
        schema: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/Reservation"
      400: 
        description: "BadRequest"
      404: 
        description: "NotFound"
      409: 
        description: "Conflict"
      500: 
        description: "InternalServerError"
    deprecated: false
```

Is there a way to get rid of that 200 OK? It's confusing as it's not a valid response.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove the default response (200 OK) by decorating the method with the `SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults` attribute.

Comment: Is there any way to add this globally rather than decorate each method in my controllers?

Comment: The attribute can be applied to a controller too. To add this behaviour globally you have to create your own `IDocumentFilter`

Comment: if anyone sees this now `SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults` is no longer in the lib. you have to explicitly add [ProducesStatus(204)] to any NoContent to suppress the default 200 that swagger adds

Answer (score 3):

As *vampiire* points out in their comment, `SwaggerResponseRemoveDefaults` is no longer in Swashbuckle. The way to achieve this now is to include both a `<response>` XML-doc **and** a `[ProducesResponseType()]` attribute to the method:

```
/// ...
/// <response code="201">Returns the newly reserved tickets</response>
/// <response code="400">If the input parameters are invalid</response>
/// ...
[HttpPost]
[Route("reservations")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
...
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReserveTickets([FromBody] ReserveTicketsRequest reserveTicketRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

This will remove the default 200 response. It's taken from [Microsoft's Swashbuckle documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#describe-response-types) on Swashbuckle 5.5.0 and ASP.NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 1):

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.OperationFilter<Api.Swagger.RemoveDefaultResponse>();
        });

   public class RemoveDefaultResponse : IOperationFilter
   {

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Responses.TryGetValue("200", out var response)) {
            if (response.Description == "Success") {
                operation.Responses.Remove("200");
            }
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: Useful, but removes it even if you have a default `///<response code="200">Success</response>` which is common. To ensure it isn't removed you need to use a value other than "Success". Is there no other way or fix? I'm surprised Swashbuckle does this.